# Handlebar compiled html not recognizing template function in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

The project I am on is currently using Backbone.js to create a website and is using Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/) as the templating system.  I am attempting to create a sub-view that gets values from a json document into a corresponding template and then return that to a parent view.

The problem I am running into is that when I use

`Handlebars.Compile(referenceViewTemplate)`

it then doesn't recognize the `template` function when I try to replace the tokens using

`this.template({ identifier: value })`

The template code is:

```
<div id="reference-template">
  <div class="id">{{id}}</div>
  <div class="reference">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

The backbone model is:

```
define(['underscore','backbone'], 
function(_, Backbone){
  var reference = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){}
  });
  return reference;
});
```

The backbone collection code is:

```
define(['underscore','backbone','models/reference'], 
  function(_, Backbone, Reference){
  var References = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Reference,
    parse:function(response){ return response; }
  });
  return new References;
});
```

The code in the parent view which calls the reference view is:

```
this.ref = new ReferenceView();
this.ref.model = this.model.page_refs; //page_refs is the section in the json which has the relevant content 
this.ref.render(section); //section is the specific part of the json which should be rendered in the view
```

And the code in the ReferenceView is:

```
define([
  // These are path alias that we configured in our bootstrap
  'jquery','underscore','backbone','handlebars',
  'models/reference','collections/references','text!templates/reference.html'],
  function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, Reference, References, referenceViewTemplate) {
    var ReferenceView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //Define the default template
    template: Handlebars.Compiler(referenceViewTemplate),   

    el: ".overlay-references",

    model: new Reference,

    events:{},

    initialize : function() {
      this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
      return this;
    },

    // Render function
    render : function(section) {
       //this is where it says "TypeError: this.template is not a function" 
       $(this.el).append(this.template(References.get(section).get("content")));
       return this;
    }
});
```

I know this is a lot to read through and I appreciate anyone taking the time to do so, please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that apparently I was using the wrong function to compile the html.  For some reason I typed in `Handlebars.Compiler` instead of `Handlebars.compile`

This hasn't solved all the problems in my project (template is being passed back now, but without the values entered), but at least it's a step forward.

Comment: The compiled template function wants an object, `{id: ..., content: ...}` in your case, `References.get(section).get("content")` probably isn't that format, you'll usually want a `toJSON()` call somewhere.